# Using Common Service Locator outside Main Project

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, structuremap, common-service-locator

I recently made the jump from StructureMap to Ninject.  All was smooth sailing until I realised that Ninject doesn't have a version of StructureMap's ObjectFactory (service locator).

I discovered Common Service Locator which provides the Service Locator Pattern with any IOC container including Ninject.  It works great inside my 'start-up' project - e.g. WebSite.  But if I try to access ServiceLocator.Current from subprojects, e.g. Core or Data it seems that CommonServiceLocator doesn't know about any of my Dependency mappings.

How do I use Common Service Locator from a sub-project?

N.B. I am aware of the debate about ServiceLocator as a pattern/anti-pattern.  I've found that there is a trade-off between ServiceLocator as an anti-pattern and Anaemic Domain Model as an anti-pattern - *sometimes* its just much easier & maintainable to use a service locator.

Comment: > _sometimes_ its just much easier & maintainable to use a service locator.

I can't say that I agree to that statement at all but anyway...

Do you have any code that shows how you setup the NInject locator adapter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for Ninject equivalent of StructureMap's ObjectFactory.GetInstance() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576238/looking-for-ninject-equivalent-of-structuremaps-objectfactory-getinstance-met)

Comment: Bringing in CSL for no reason because you want to ignore the advice re SL doesnt change the fact that you're looking for a way to do SL hence my VTC

Answer (score 4):

Use [factories](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/) instead of accessing the container directly. This keeps your application free from a specific container and prevents the usage of a service locator.

The only situations where you have to access the kernel is once in your composition root and in some very rare situations where you aren't in control of the object creation. In these situations you can still assign the kernel to a singleton object or use the ServiceLocator to make it accessable from anywhere.

ServiceLocator is a static object. Therefore there is no difference from where you are accessing it. I assume that you are accessing the ServiceLocator before it is fully confugured.

Answer (score 0):

Without entering the debate on the use of a service locator, have you tried this NuGet Package [CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter)?

When I decide I want one, this is what I've used.