# How does ObjectFactory.GetInstance<>() in Ninject work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

While restructing code in one of my older projects, I have across a static class using DI. Below is how it looks...

```
public static class AccountTypeHelper
{
    private static readonly IAccountTypeProvider AccountTypeProvider;

    static AccountTypeHelper()
    {
        AccountTypeProvider = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAccountTypeProvider>();
    }

    public static string AppName()
    {
        return AccountTypeProvider.GetAccountType().AppName;
    }
}
```

Well, everything works just fine. The factory picks up the correct provider and all goes well.

But I trying to understand how this line of code works.

```
AccountTypeProvider = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAccountTypeProvider>();
```

I tried googling for what `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` does but couldnt find any help. Can some one pls help me understand or point to a resource.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectFactory` is a static [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) class (ok there may be other DI containers with same-name types..).
Ninject does not feature an `ObjectFactory`. So either you're not using Ninject but a different DI container or you're using Ninject but then you'll have to look for `ObjectFactory` in your own code base or on in a 3rd party dll.

Behind the scenes this call would need to translate to something like:

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; internal set; }

    public T GetInstance<T>()
    {
        return Kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}

// somewhere initialization of static instance needs to be done:
ObjectFactory.Kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

also see [Looking for Ninject equivalent of StructureMap's ObjectFactory.GetInstance() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576238/looking-for-ninject-equivalent-of-structuremaps-objectfactory-getinstance-met)
and [examplar ObjectFactory.cs implementation](https://github.com/triggerfish/Common/blob/master/src/Triggerfish.Ninject/ObjectFactory.cs)

Answer (score 0):

For Ninject to work correctly, you usually need to tell it which class to instantiate when you call `Get` or similar. This is done by binding a class which implements the interface using something like the following code

```
Bind<IAccountTypeProvider>().To<SomeAccountTypeProvider>();
```

From then on, when you call `Get<IAccountTypeProvider>()`, it will return a new instance of `SomeAccountTypeProvider`

**Edit**: Forgot to mention that Ninject does not have an equivalent to StructureMaps `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAccountTypeProvider>()`. You can instead use something like below

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IAccountTypeProvider>().To<SomeAccountTypeProvider>();

IAccountTypeProvider provider = ninjectKernel.Get<IAccountTypeProvider>();
//returns an instance of SomeAccountTypeProvider
```

More information [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject)